# Whenever i am trying to run this code it is showing this error

Tags: react-native

```
Whenever i am trying to run this code it is showing this **error**
```

```js
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <Text style={styles.title}>**First** React Native Apps Here</Text>
    
        <View>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYnqNyLNEiAyVI293IZkUW56d2mLAsV35N4w&usqp=CAU",
            }}
            style={{ width: 305, height: 159 }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.title}>First React Native Apps Here</Text>
        </View>
        <NativeRouter>
          <Link to="/login">
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/home">
            {" "}
            <Text>Home</Text>
          </Link>
    
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          </Routes>
        </NativeRouter>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>;
```

*Error*: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child*

Answer (score 0):

`NativeRouter` should have 1 single child like

```
<NativeRouter>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Switch>
      <Route />
      <Route />
    </Switch>
  </View>
</NativeRouter>
```

Detail [Here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/api/NativeRouter)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `several elements` in `NativeRouter` However, `NativeRouter` allows only `one element`. So you have to wrap it around `View`.

You can see through [examples of official documents.](https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/example/Basic)

you can fix

```js
<NativeRouter>
  <View>
    <Link to="/login">
      <Text>Login</Text>
    </Link>
    <Link to="/home">
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </Link>
    
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  </View>
</NativeRouter>
```